# Как проверить, воспроизводится ли какой-нибудь звук?

Tags: windows, delphi

Изначально, сделал через функцию `GetPeakValue`, которая работает корректно, если звук играет, к примеру, через плеер или какой-нибудь vlc, mpc.
Если же это браузер, то показывает 0.

Вот ссылка по теме [GetPeakValue](https://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=336494)

Какая универсальная функция есть чтобы определить что какое-либо приложение "издает" звук в системе?